# Receiving an error using Union all

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

```
select cou_name as County_Name, count(*) as count
from sdrp15_cosd 
where sd_code in (select sd_code from sdrp15_submission_log where QA_DATE IS null)
union all
select cou_name as County_Name, count(*) 
from sdrp15_cosd 
where sd_code in (select sd_code from sdrp15_submission_log where QA_DATE IS not null)
GROUP BY COU_NAME;
```

I am trying to find the county names and for each county i am displaying a total count of when a linked table displays a connected column of being null or not null.

I am receiving the error:

> not a single-group function

Comment: use separate group by in first Select Statement

Comment: How do you know whether a row represents the case of QA_DATE IS null or QA_DATE IS not null? The result set you get is the same as a single query that just counts sdrp15_cosd records by country name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select cou_name as County_Name, count(*) as count
from sdrp15_cosd 
where sd_code in (select sd_code from sdrp15_submission_log where QA_DATE IS 
null)
GROUP BY COU_NAME 
union all
select cou_name as County_Name, count(*) 
from sdrp15_cosd 
where sd_code in (select sd_code from sdrp15_submission_log where QA_DATE IS     
not null)
GROUP BY COU_NAME;
```